# Time difference between Python and MicroPython on ESP32

Tags: python, esp32, micropython

I'm working with the utime module in MicroPython. I've noticed a time difference when converting to Epoch time between the utime.time() on the ESP32 in MicroPython and time.time() in normal Python. I'm also using a DS3231 RTC board which is connected to an ESP32 to make my time persistent.

Here is the code:

```
from machine import Pin, ADC, reset, RTC, I2C
import DS3231
import utime

#setup DS3231 RTC
i2c = I2C(sda = Pin(22), scl=Pin(21))
ds = DS3231.DS3231(i2c)
#set time
tm = ds.DateTime() # Time from DS3231 which is accurate to my computer time

#ds.DateTime returns this [2020, 4, 15, 3, 12, 42, 4] which is Y,M,D,day of week,H,M,S
tm_tup = (tm[0], tm[1], tm[2], tm[4], tm[5], 0,0,0) #convert to tuple to set ESP32 clock which is 
#supposed to also set utime
RTC().datetime(tm_tup) #sets time on ESP32
utc  = 946684800 + utime.time() # since utime starts at 1/1/2000 and utc starts 1/1/1970
print(tm)  #time from DS3231 RTC
print(utime.time()) 
print(utc) #added to utime.time() to make UTC
```

The `ds.DateTime()` function returns the same time as my computer in a list. I rearrange the values into a tuple to set the `RTC.datetime()` which is supposed to sync with the utime module. All I really need is an accurate UTC timestamp. Local time is ok.

There is a discrepancy when I check `utime.time()` against Python's `time.time()` module even though I set my DS3231 to the exact time on my computer. The outputs are as follows. I ran the Python script about 30 secs after running the ESP32 version.

ESP32 output

```
[2020, 4, 15, 3, 15, 46, 49] #Exact date time from my computer
640389600
1587074400
```

Python Output

```
>>> import time
>>> print (time.time())
1586983668.94813
```

Just curious as to why there is such a difference.

Comment: The parameters to `RTC.datetime()` are apparently (year, month, day, weekday, hours, minutes, seconds, subseconds).  You are passing zero for both minutes and seconds, thus producing a time that's always an exact hour.  The fact that the return value of `utime.time()` is an exact multiple of 3600 supports this.

Comment: I think the weekday went on the end for RTC. They are like you said for the DS 3231.@jasonharper